# Why does Finder show 104 GB used on my hard disk, when the parts only add up to 55 GB?

Tags: macos, disk-space

I have this weird problem with my disk space. A screenshot should explain it perfectly.

[image: SpaceScreenshot]

Just look at the numbers. 104GB of space that is used by Macintosh HD, but when you sum up the values below it, you can barely reach 55GB.

You can also see here that 74GB are occupied by "Other" files. I really looked through my folders and files and, as I said, there is no way that I occupy that much disk space.

[image: MacStorage]

Is it a bug or are there any hidden files that I should be aware of? What can I do with this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no bug. You're just assuming that Finder will show you all files by default. It will not. If you want the truth, you can use the command line (a.k.a. Terminal)

```
[SaxDaddy's Mac ~]$  df -h
Filesystem           Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1          233Gi  204Gi   28Gi    88% 53608098 7370716   88%   /
```

The utility `df` will show you a high level of all attached disks. Here's where it gets more complicated. Unfortunately, there's no command line utility that gives you the pretty, categorized breakdown that Finder will. But you can use `du` ,the disk usage statistics tool, to see what your top files/folders sorted descendingly.

```
sudo du -a / 2>/dev/null|sort -n -r|head -n 35
```

This command will show your largest 35 file/folder entries. NOTE that you may see duplication from this output, e.g., If `/home/Tetsujin/big_file` is 50GB, then you'd also see `/home/Tetsujin` in the output.

Comment: du is actually pretty helpful. There are lots of additional parameters you can use to filter the results. You'll find more information on the web, for example here: http://foldersize.com/disk-space-management-on-unix-linux-systems/